# Unable to install Apricity OS from USB

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome

I am trying to install Apricity OS (Gnome version, based on Arch Linux) on my laptop. I have downloaded the ISO and created a bootable USB installer using Rufus utility (http://rufus.akeo.ie/) on my 32 GB pen drive.
Now, I am able to boot my laptop using from the USB but when I start the installation it fails. Below is a snapshot of my screen.
[image: Snapshot]

I searched the internet but I am unable to find much help on this. Please let me know if I can provide more details.

Thank you!

Comment: @Thomas This worked well! I owe you a beer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like rufus didn't do a good job as the filesystem label seems to be missing.

If you have a second linux machine you simply could use

```
dd if=apricity_os-07.2016-aspen-v2-gnome.iso of=/dev/<usb-drive> bs=1M; eject /dev/<usb-drive>
```

or use [USBWriter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/usbwriter/) for Windows.

Comment: this guide also looks good https://zodiacfireworks.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/hpc-adventure-01-installing-apricityos/